# Как добавить запись на json файл?

Tags: javascript, html, http, fetch

```
form.addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const formData = new FormData(form);
  const name = formData.get("name");
  form.reset();

  let user = {
    name: name,
  };

  let res = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5500/data.json", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(user),
  });

  let result = res.json();
  alert(result);
});
```

При отправке POST запроса получаю 405статус. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Логичный вопрос — а почему вы решили, что вот этот вот сервер на порту 5500 в принципе должен был обработать ваш POST-запрос?

Comment: @andreymal то-есть такой сервер сможет обработать только get-запрос?

Comment: Сервер будет обрабатывать то, что он умеет обрабатывать

Comment: если у вас webpack, то нет смысла вобще использовать fetch для загрузки статических файлов. данные берете через [import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43735486/load-static-json-file-in-webpack)/require: import login from '../fixtures/login.json';

Comment: `Что я делаю не так?` - как вариант протокол не тот. Такой УРЛ может обрабатываться только методом `GET` и не более того. Для работы с сервером нужно знать какие запросы и с какими данными он вообще поддерживает.

Comment: @ksa любой УРЛ с протоколами http и https может обрабатываться любым http-методом

Comment: @andreymal, если сервер тебе пришлет ответ с 404 или с 405, на твой "любой" - не унывай. :) Он ведь его обработал.

Comment: @ksa ну да, а может прислать и 200 если захочет. Это деталь реализации конкретного сервера, а не что-то связанное с протоколом

Comment: @andreymal, я понял суть твоего замечания. Вместо слова "метод" я написал "протокол". Я имел ввиду именно метод. Если отправить `GET` на `http://127.0.0.1:5500/data.json` - получишь данные. А вот если `POST` - получай 405. Де на такой метод более ничего не получишь...